# Switching hrefs for two links within an h6 tag

Tags: php, html, regex, domdocument

Let's say I have a string of html. Let's call it `$html` just to be original and it looks like this:

```
<h6><a href="1a">ABC</a> | <a href="1b" target="_blank">XXX</a></h6>
<p>fffffff
<h6><a href="2a">DEF</a> | <a href="2b" target="_blank">XXX</a></h6>
<p>ddddddd
<h6><a href="3a">GHI</a> | <a href="3b" target="_blank">XXX</a></h6>
<p>bbbbbbb
```

I want to take the `href` and `target` from the second link in each `H6` tag and use it for the first link in the tag, then erase the `|` and the second link entirely so it would look like this:

```
<h6><a href="1b" target="_blank">ABC</a></h6>
<p>fffffff
<h6><a href="2b" target="_blank">DEF</a></h6>
<p>ddddddd
<h6><a href="3b" target="_blank">GHI</a></h6>
<p>bbbbbbb
```

I know I need need to use an HTML parser but I'm not sure how to use it like this. What's the simplest way to go about doing this? I'm doing this in PHP.

Comment: From my experience, DOMDocument (since it's native), but it's a hell of little quirks (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$input='<h6><a href="1a">ABC</a> | <a href="1b" target="_blank">XXX</a></h6>\n' .
       '<p>fffffff\n' .
       '<h6><a href="2a">DEF</a> | <a href="2b" target="_blank">XXX</a></h6>\n' .
       '<p>ddddddd\n' .
       '<h6><a href="3a">GHI</a> | <a href="3b" target="_blank">XXX</a></h6>\n' .
       '<p>bbbbbbb';

echo preg_replace(
     '#<h6><a href=".*?">(.*?)</a> \| <a href="(.*?)" target="(.*?)">.*?</a></h6>#',
     '<h6><a href="$2" target="$3">$1</a></h6>',
     $input
);
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://codepad.org/QmhPqGlP

Comment: That works! I used your code as a starting point and finally figured out the difference between .*? and (.*?).

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, HTML isn't a regular language, and therefore can't be parsed completely by a regular expression.  However, in this instance, you can accomplish what you need with a regex.  Replace:

```
<h6><a href=".*?">(.*?)</a> \| <a href="(.*?)" target="(.*?)">.*?</a></h6>
```

With:

```
<h6><a href="$2" target="$3">$1</a></h6>
```

This, of course, assumes there aren't any surprises: that is, your tags don't have other attributes, like classes or IDs, and everything is in consistent case.  If they do, you have a slightly more complicated problem that will require either a full parser, or multiple regexes.

Comment: This works for each h6 tag, but how do I get at the strings from the $html? is it just like preg_replace('<h6><a href=".*?">(.*?)</a> \| <a href="(.*?)" target="(.*?)">.*?</a></h6>','<h6><a href="$2" target="$3">$1</a></h6>',$html)? How do I teach myself how to write regex?

Comment: Thanks you for your help though I am now learning regex at long last.